# Problemexcel Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to when the D column any cell has value empty, in the E column should be automatically come empty

[image]

Comment: Thank you so very much dear **Teylyn**, my problem is solved

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. That's how you can say "thank you" around here.

Answer (score 3):

Your formula compares with 0, but the cell is not 0, it is empty. You may want to check if the cell has a number, like this:

```
=IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(D3)),"",IF(C3>D3,"improved",IF(C3<=D3,"not improved")))
```

[image]

Or, a bit simpler setup:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(D3),IF(C3>D3,"improved",IF(C3<=D3,"not improved")),"")
```

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.